# if statement executing the first condition when it shouldn't

Tags: javascript

the conditional statement under getWinner keeps outputting the first condition of "It's a tie" even when the computer and player have two different answers. I can't seem to figure out why. Any help would be appreciated!

```js
function getInput() {
  console.log("Please choose either 'rock', 'paper', or 'scissors'.");
  return prompt();
}
console.log(getInput());

function randomPlay() {
  var randomNumber = Math.random();
  if (randomNumber < 0.33) {
    return "rock";
  } else if (randomNumber < 0.66) {
    return "paper";
  } else {
    return "scissors";
  }
}
console.log(randomPlay());

function getPlayerMove(move) {
  if (!move) {
    move = getInput();
  }
  return move;
}

function getComputerMove(move) {
  if (!move) {
    move = getInput();
  }
  return move;
}

function getWinner(playerMove, computerMove) {
  if (playerMove === computerMove) {
    return ("It's a tie!");
  } else if (playerMove === "rock") {
    if (computerMove === "paper") {
      return "paper wins";
    } else {
      return "rock wins";
    }
  } else if (playerMove === "paper") {
    if (computerMove === "rock") {
      return "paper wins";
    } else {
      return "scissors wins";
    }
  } else if (playerMove === "scissors") {
    if (computerMove === "paper") {
      return "scissors wins";
    } else {
      return "rock wins";
    }
  }
}

console.log(getWinner());
```

Comment: Well, you are calling the function with `getWinner()`, so both arguments are `undefined` (=> equal). You have to pass the values you want to compare. Not sure what exactly you want to pass though... how did you expect `playerMove` and `computerMove` to magically get values from?

Comment: `getPlayerMove` is never called, so that's not where the problem is

Comment: I think you mean the conditional under `getWinner`.

Comment: yes I do! I will edit!

Answer (score 1):

You're never calling `getPlayerMove` or `getComputerMove`, so you have nothing to compare. You should be calling them as the arguments to `getWinner`

```js
function getInput() {
  console.log("Please choose either 'rock', 'paper', or 'scissors'.");
  return prompt();
}

function randomPlay() {
  var randomNumber = Math.random();
  if (randomNumber < 0.33) {
    return "rock";
  } else if (randomNumber < 0.66) {
    return "paper";
  } else {
    return "scissors";
  }
}
console.log(randomPlay());

function getPlayerMove(move) {
  if (!move) {
    move = getInput();
  }
  return move;
}

function getComputerMove(move) {
  if (!move) {
    move = getInput();
  }
  return move;
}

function getWinner(playerMove, computerMove) {
  if (playerMove === computerMove) {
    return ("It's a tie!");
  } else if (playerMove === "rock") {
    if (computerMove === "paper") {
      return "paper wins";
    } else {
      return "rock wins";
    }
  } else if (playerMove === "paper") {
    if (computerMove === "rock") {
      return "paper wins";
    } else {
      return "scissors wins";
    }
  } else if (playerMove === "scissors") {
    if (computerMove === "paper") {
      return "scissors wins";
    } else {
      return "rock wins";
    }
  }
}

console.log(getWinner(getPlayerMove(), getComputerMove()));
```

Comment: I assume `getRandomPlay` should be called for/instead of `getComputerMove`, but whatever..

Comment: Or maybe `getComputerMove` should call `getRandomPlay` instead of `getInput`. But that's really orthogonal to the problem of getting the `if` to work.

Comment: Since `getWinner` takes a `computerMove` argument, it seems like `getComputerMove()` should be the right function to provide that value.

Comment: This just makes the prompt pop up 4 times and still brings up "It's a tie" every time"

Comment: It only pops up twice for me. I enter rock then paper, it logs "paper wins"

Answer (score 0):

In you last line you called:

```
Console.log (getWinner ());
```

In JavaScript this is the same as:

```
Console.log (getWinner (null,null));
```

Well technically both parameters would be undefined and not null but they would in fact be equal.

You need to prompt to user for valuse or provide them.

Comment: It's actually equivalent to `getWinner(undefined, undefined)`

Answer (score 0):

Several errors -

1. Both `getComputerMove` and `getPlayerMove` are
2. you write a random number to the console but should store the number in a variable first
3. The variable `move` never has it's value set,
4. You call the function `getWinner` with no parameters - getWinner compares the two parameters, both of which are null, because they are both null it gives you **it's a tie**

Debug basics:

use comments or write on paper what values the different variables should have at several different stages in the program, run the program using console(log) to display a message and the variables at each stage, then fix the errors on by one in the order they

Running code with helpful console(log) statements should give you messages like this to work from:

User entered 'paper' 
Computer said 'rock' 
getComputerMove returns 'scissors' 
Comparing 'null' and 'rock' in function getWinner etc.

You then use the statements to fix as you go, commenting out the debug statements where it works, when finished you can delete them. You can also comment out complex lines and hardcode values for variables to check the later parts work,then put the user input and random part back in.

Tip: if you call the random function more than once it will cause issues, you don't want to write a random word to the console and use the random function a second time to store the value - because it will probably differ from the first value.

Answer (score 0):

Rock paper scissors:

```
function RockPaperScissors(){
  this.wins = {user:0, computer:0}; this.draws = 0;
  this.play = function(choose){
    var rps = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];
    var yw = 'You Won!', yl = 'You Lost!';
    var idx = 0, cmp = Math.floor(Math.random()*4), ch;
    if(rps.indexOf){
      idx = rps.indexOf(choose);
    }
    else{
      for(var i=0,l=rps.length; i<l; i++){
        if(rps[i] === choose){
          idx = i;
        }
      }
    }
    if(cmp === idx){
      this.draws++;
      return "It's a Draw.";
    }
    else if(cpm === 0){
      ch = ' The computer chose rock.';
      if(idx === 1){
        this.wins.user++;
        return yw+ch;
      }
      else if(idx === 2){
        this.wins.computer++;
        return yl+ch;
      }
    }
    else if(cpm === 1){
      ch = ' The computer chose paper.';
      if(idx === 0){
        this.wins.computer++;
        return yl+ch;
      }
      else if(idx === 2){
        this.wins.user++;
        return yw+ch;
      }
    }
    else if(cpm === 2){
      ch = ' The computer chose scissors.';
      if(idx === 0){
        this.wins.user++;
        return yw+ch;
      }
      else if(idx === 1){
        this.wins.computer++
        return yl+ch;
      }
    }
    else{
      return 'Your Entry Was Invalid. Please Try Again.';
    }
  }
}
var game1 = new RockPaperScissors;
console.log(game1.play('rock'));
console.log('Game 1 Score -> user:'+game1.wins.user+' , computer:'+game1.wins.computer+' , draws:'+game1.draws);
console.log(game1.play('scissors'));
console.log(game1.play('paper'));
var game2 = new RockPaperScissors;
console.log('Game 1 Score -> user:'+game1.wins.user+' , computer:'+game1.wins.computer+' , draws:'+game1.draws);
console.log(game2.play('paper'));
console.log('Game 2 Score -> user:'+game2.wins.user+' , computer:'+game2.wins.computer+' , draws:'+game2.draws);
console.log('Game 1 Score -> user:'+game1.wins.user+' , computer:'+game1.wins.computer+' , draws:'+game1.draws);
console.log('Notice that game 1 is not affected by game 2.');
```

Just made this. I think it should work.